# Implementation of Google oAuth with local top level domain

Tags: google-oauth, tld

We want to use google oauth for an internal application, something like `http://corpwiki.internal`. Obviously using that as the redirect URI doesn't work.

One workaround would be to use something like `wiki.mycooperation.com` as redirect URI and redirecting from there to `http://corpwiki.internal`. But that feels like an ugly hack.

Are there any nicer workarounds?